# biblio style is giving reference with inconsistent page numbers

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to change by bibliography style using a .bst file found at  https://github.com/martiabr/TTK4150-course-summary/blob/master/abbrv_networks.bst

But I am having an issue.

When I use this style, the page numbers are being formatted differently for different reference and I am not sure why.
For some references, the page numbers are shown as `pp. 25-37` while others are just `203-221`

the image probably gives a better idea. [image]

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but any help is appreciated.

Edit: I probably have an idea. I went through the .bst file and I think it is because of the way references are mentioned in my .bib file. I think plain articles will not get `pp.` prefix while articles in proceedings will get the the `pp.` suffix.

Comment: I think there's nothing "wrong" here. As you note, one entry type -- `@article`, right? -- is programmed *not* to prefix `pp.` to the contents of the `pages` field, whereas another entry type -- `@inproceedings`, maybe? -- is. (If you hadn't blacked out the rest of the entry, it should be possible to make that diagnosis confidently.)

Comment: I wouldn't lose sleep over this. Some style guides want articles in journals (`@article`) to have no "pp." and other entry types (like `@inbook`, `@inproceedings`) to have "pp." for pages. (For example APA style: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/journal-article-references, https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/edited-book-chapter-references.) So if someone gave you this style for your document I would assume this is a conscious decision and expected. Just make sure your entry types in the `.bib` file are correct.